# Kafka ACL to topic based on client certificate DN, or its part

Tags: authentication, ssl, apache-kafka, authorization, ssl-certificate

I am reading through the Kafka documentation (version 0.11.0) and I would like to have authentication and authorization to topics for consumers and publishers based on its client certificate.

It should work in a way that the authorization will be granted based on DN, or just its part, like CN, email or something else.

I see that the Kafka brokers can be configured to use secure communication through TLS and to authenticate incoming connection based on client certificate. But from my point of view, that's it. That's all that Kafka broker can do with client certificate. ACL for topic should use SASL, where we can use PLAIN, Kerberos, or SCRAM.

So is it possible to authenticate client's connection based on CN name in SSL certificate and put ACL settings for the topic based on it in Kafka (kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the out of the box tools to set ACLs based on the SSL user name but the default Principal builder uses more than just the shorter CN value as the user name.

From the Confluent Online documentation at https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html

By default, the SSL user name will be of the form

> CN=writeuser,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown

One can change that by setting a customized PrincipalBuilder in server.properties like the following:

> principal.builder.class=CustomizedPrincipalBuilderClass

Comment: When defining the ACLs using kafka-acls it is important to avoid the spaces in front of commas in the FQN. I.e. do not define ACL with CN=writeruser, OU=Unknown but instead CN=writeruser,OU=Unknown...

Comment: And from what I've observed, the order is also important. Tried to provide ACLs for with principal as different order and got access denied error.